# Intent Items onClick to Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, listactivity

I have this ListActivity for displaying Items getting from my ListViewActivity.

```
public class ListTasksActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> adapterItems;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) i.getSerializableExtra("taskItems");
        String[] stringArr = i.getStringArrayExtra("adapterStringArray");
        int[] intArr = i.getIntArrayExtra("adapterIntArray");

        ListAdapter taskadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, taskItems,
                R.layout.list_item_tasks,
                stringArr,
                intArr);

        setListAdapter(taskadapter);
        adapterItems = taskItems;
        //CustomAdapterTasks customAdapterTasks = new CustomAdapterTasks((ListViewActivity) ListViewActivity.getAppContext(),);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String[] adapterString = new String[] {"location","object_id","task_subject","task_action","object"};
        int[] adapterInt = new int[]  {R.id.singleTaskLocation,R.id.singleTaskInvNumber,R.id.singleTaskSubject,R.id.singleTaskAction,R.id.singleTaskObject};

        //neue Oberflaeche starten
        Intent in = new Intent(this,ListSingleTaskActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("adapterStringArray",adapterString);
        in.putExtra("adapterIntArray",adapterInt);
        in.putExtra("taskItems",adapterItems);

        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

If I click on an Item then this happens:

```
public class ListSingleTaskActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;

    ListView mylistview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_task_layout);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) i.getSerializableExtra("taskItems");
        String[] stringArr = i.getStringArrayExtra("adapterStringArray");
        int[] intArr = i.getIntArrayExtra("adapterIntArray");

        ListAdapter taskadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, taskItems,
                R.layout.single_task_layout,
                stringArr,
                intArr)
}
```

My Problem is that i want to send the Informations from clicked Item to the new Activity and display them. The result from above Code is that he show me the whole Items. Not just the clicked one.
What is wrong?

I hope that it's clear what my problem is. If something is missing just comment

edited:

---

Now i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
        at de.example.app.ListSingleTaskActivity.onCreate(ListSingleTaskActivity.java:30)
```

It's this line:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) i.getSerializableExtra("taskItems");
```

Comment: You are sending whole List of adapteritems to the new activity. And in the new activity too you have a list view. I would suggest to further read and understand concepts.

Comment: You are sending complete list, just send `adapter.get(position)`

Comment: oh it was so easy thank you! why downvote?

Comment: @raymondis some people downvote if they simply don't like something about a question instead of commenting, don't worry about it, it happens to everyone. That said, do try to keep your code samples short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ListTasksActivity send selected data:

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,ListSingleTaskActivity.class);

in.putExtra("adapterStringArray",adapterString.get(position));
in.putExtra("adapterIntArray",adapterInt[position]);
in.putExtra("taskItems",adapterItems.get(position));

startActivity(in);
```

Comment: adapterString is arrayy String[] adapterString = new String[] {"location","object_id","task_subject","task_action","object"};

Comment: I get another error know... can you help me please? :)

Comment: where your sending that task items ?

Comment: it comes from here: in.putExtra("taskItems", adapterItems.get(position)); @NehaAgarwal i don't know if this can help me

Comment: you are trying get arraylist of maps in second activity but actually you are sending just as single Hashmap look at my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

you are sending whole array thats why you see entire objects inside onclick send only selected objects like below:

```
in.putExtra("adapterStringArray",adapterString.get[position]);
in.putExtra("adapterIntArray",adapterInt[position]);
in.putExtra("taskItems",adapterItems.get(position));
```

For second crash issue try this

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)   intent.getSerializableExtra("taskItems");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your OnItem click listener like below then it will work

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String[] adapterString = new String[] {"location","object_id","task_subject","task_action","object"};
        int[] adapterInt = new int[]  {R.id.singleTaskLocation,R.id.singleTaskInvNumber,R.id.singleTaskSubject,R.id.singleTaskAction,R.id.singleTaskObject};

        //neue Oberflaeche starten
        Intent in = new Intent(this,ListSingleTaskActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("adapterStringArray",adapterString.get(position));
        in.putExtra("adapterIntArray",adapterInt[position]);
        in.putExtra("taskItems",adapterItems.get(position));

        startActivity(in);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are passing complete arrays in the intent.

Actually you need to pass the value of the item which has been clicked in the intent.
Use this getItemAtPosition(position) and send it in the in.putExtra then only you would be able to get the selected item.

For more info. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html